# register_shutdown_function Or ignore_user_abort?

Tags: php, performance, background-process

Hey i've seen people recommend each of them, One calimed register_shutdown_function to be better but without explination.

I'm talking about which is better to send a response back and still preform other tasks.
I Wondered what really is the better method and why.

**EDIT:** 
In the [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) documentation, someone published the following method:

```
<?php 
function endOutput($endMessage){ 
    ignore_user_abort(true); 
    set_time_limit(0); 
    header("Connection: close"); 
    header("Content-Length: ".strlen($endMessage)); 
    echo $endMessage; 
    echo str_repeat("\r\n", 10); // just to be sure 
    flush(); 
} 

// Must be called before any output 
endOutput("thank you for visiting, have a nice day'); 

sleep(100); 
mail("you@yourmail.com", "ping", "im here"); 
?>
```

Could it be better then any of the functions i stated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In older versions of PHP (<4.1.0 under Apache), register_shutdown_function() would ensure that the connection was closed before your shutdown functions ran.  This is no longer the case.  The endOutput() function in your edit should indeed do what you want, provided you don't have any output buffers open.  Though, it does set the script to be able to run forever if necessary, which could be annoying if it goes into an infinite loop (especially during debugging).  You might want to change set_time_limit() to use a value that actually reflects how many seconds the script should take.

It's probably best to avoid register_shutdown_function() if you don't need it, since it has some other odd behavior (such as not being able to add a second layer of shutdown functions to run if the first shutdown function calls exit()).

Answer (score 1):

ignore_user_abort() tells PHP/Apache to not terminate execution when the user disconnects. register_shutdown_function simply allows you to do some cleanup while PHP is in the process of shutting down.

register_shut_down is only useful if you need to do some cleanup that PHP's normal shutdown routines wouldn't take care, e.g. removing a manually created lock file, flipping a bit in a DB record somewhere, etc...

Comment: Think of ignore_user_abort() as standing on the ramp at the bungee jump and refusing to jump, while register_shutdown_function is you writing your Last Will and Testament on your way down to the bottom of the gorge.